# Git archive a directory without the directory path

Tags: git, archive

I've found a few references of how to do this with the 7zip cli:
https://superuser.com/questions/340046/create-an-archive-from-a-directory-without-the-directory-name-being-added-to-the?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#

But specifically I want to use `git archive` to create a zip file of a subdirectory, but I want the archive to not include the subdirectory name as a top file.

closest I've got is this:
`git archive --format zip HEAD ./dist/* > deploy.zip`

but its producing a zip file with a parent directory called dist/

My folder structure looks something like this;

```
project
  - .git
  - src
  - dist
    - my files and folders
```

What I'd like to do is archive only the "dist" directory with all of its contents at the top level of the resulting archive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [git-archive documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) (*):

```
git archive --format zip HEAD:dist/ > deploy.zip
```

Essentially [tree-ish](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) can have the format `<rev>:<path>`.

*: The example from git doc that inspired the answer is "*Put everything in the current head’s Documentation/ directory into git-1.4.0-docs.zip, with the prefix git-docs/*"